# In VS Code, how do I adjust the "drag to highlight" scroll speed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

This is only happening in VS Code. When dragging to highlight.  As soon as I get to the edge of the screen the entire line will be highlighted.  and the pointer end up at the edge of the file.

Comment: I sifted through all the settings I thought relevant, but there does not appear to be a way to turn that off.  You could always hold shift or ctrl + shift and the arrow keys to highlight which won't jump to the end (unless there is no white space character when using ctrl + shift)

Comment: yes, that has been my workaround.  But I keep forgetting and then I'll suddenly be at the end of my file for no good reason.  It's frustrating.